# Wordpress: create list of thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, list

I'm new to WP so I'm still finding my way around

I want to create a simple list of thumbnails. In html I have done this like so

```
    <section class="imgSection">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="images/personal01.jpg"><img src="images/personal01.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/personal03.jpg"><img src="images/personal03.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/personal04.jpg"><img src="images/personal04.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="images/personal05.jpg"><img src="images/personal05.jpg" /></a></li>

      </ul>
    </section>
```

In WP I have simply added thumbnails to a page with Upload/Insert and picked thumbnail from the Add Media window.

I have used this php to add the content to the page

```
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <section class="imgSection">

        <?php the_content(); ?>

    </section>  

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This outputs code like this, each "a" tag is wrapped in an "p" tag

```
    <section class="imgSection">
       <p><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal14.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-32" title="personal14" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal14-221x150.jpg" alt="" width="221" height="150" /></a></p>
       <p><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal13.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-31" title="personal13" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal13-199x150.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="150" /></a></p>
       <p><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal12.jpg"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-30" title="personal12" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/personal12-199x150.jpg" alt="" width="199" height="150" /></a></p>
    </section>
```

Is it possible to surround each "a" tag width a "li" instead of a "p" tag so it's like the original html code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

[[gallery]](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode)

There are many options you can set, including the tag you'd like each item wrapped in.  You don't need to insert the images into the post or page, just upload them to the gallery for that post or page and use the shortcode.  If you're placing the shortcode in the template file you'll need to reference it like this: `<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery]'); ?>`.  You can place your options in the shortcode this way too.